# Odata relative url in batch request

Tags: .net, http, odata, simple.odata.client

I am developing a OData client for third party service, which is written in SAP. When generating Odata Http batch requests, the internal requests of the batch request has absolute url and the SAP server does not consider it as a valid request. It needs just the relative url (without even any slash) for emample "Details" is valid but "/Detals" is not valid. I have tried using Simple OData and Microsoft's HttpClient libraries but they both generate the absolute url. Is there a way to generate relative urls using any of the libraries that support .Net ?

For example

Below request is considered as VALID:

```
--batch_2eeb01f1-9e99-444b-9864-ec1cd77f9c68
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="abcd"

--abcd
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST **Details** HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
Content-Type: application/json
```

---

Below request is considered as IN-VALID:

```
--batch_2eeb01f1-9e99-444b-9864-ec1cd77f9c68
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="abcd"

--abcd
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST **/Details** HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Please ignore ** in POST urls above. **Details** => Details and **/Details** => /Details.

Comment: Looks like the SAP product at other end is configured as mentioned in the article https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/06/batch-request-in-sap-gateway